# Best way to Handle state for a React UI Component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to React. I started using it for creating a design system library in my work, so it's basically standalone UI components to use in React apps.

I adopted a certain way in handling the state of my component (hovered, focused, pressed) and the events. That's an example of a button component:

```
import { composeEventHandlers } from '../../utils/events';
import './button.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames';
// ...

type Size =
  | 'small'
  | 'medium'
  | 'large';

type Type = 
  | 'primary'
  | 'secondary'
  | 'outline';

interface ButtonProps {
  id?: string;
  children: string | string[];
  size?: Size;
  type?: Type;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  loading?: boolean;
  pressed?: boolean;
  textAlign?: TextAlign; 

  onClick?(): void;
  onFocus?(): void;
  onBlur?(): void;
  onMouseEnter?(): void;
  onMouseLeave?(): void;
}

/**
 * Button component
 */
export const Button = ({
  children,
  size,
  type,
  disabled = false,
  loading = false,
  pressed = false,
  fullWidth,
  onClick,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
  onMouseEnter,
  onMouseLeave,
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(pressed);

  const handleClick = _ => {
    setIsPressed(true);
  }

  const handleFocus = _ => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  }

  const handleBlur = _ => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  }

  const handleMouseEnter = _ => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  }

  const handleMouseLeave = _ => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  }

  const prefix = usePrefix();
  const buttonClasses = classNames(
    `${prefix}--btn`,
    `${prefix}--btn--${type}`,
    `${prefix}--btn--${abbreviate(size)}`,
    {
      [`${prefix}--btn--full-width`]: fullWidth,
      [`${prefix}--btn--disabled`]: disabled,
      [`${prefix}--btn--loading`]: loading,
      [`${prefix}--btn--pressed`]: isPressed,
      [`${prefix}--btn--hovered`]: isHovered,
      [`${prefix}--btn--focused`]: isFocused,
    }
  );
  const eventHandlers = {
    onClick: composeEventHandlers([onClick, handleClick]),
    onFocus: composeEventHandlers([onFocus, handleFocus]),
    onBlur: composeEventHandlers([onBlur, handleBlur]),
    onMouseEnter: composeEventHandlers([onMouseEnter, handleMouseEnter]),
    onMouseLeave: composeEventHandlers([onMouseLeave, handleMouseLeave]),
  }

  const buttonMarkup = 
    <button
      type="button"
      className={buttonClasses}
     {...eventHandlers}
    >
      {loading
        ? <Loader size='small' type={type === 'primary' ? 'secondary' : 'primary'></Loader>
        : children
      }
    </button>
  ;

  return buttonMarkup;
};
```

In my css, i will change the component's style according to the css classes defined in runtime by the state of the component:

```
.#{$prefix}--btn {
  // ...

  // SIZES
  &.#{$prefix}--btn--sm {
    width: auto;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  // ...

  // COLORS
  &.#{$prefix}--btn--primary {
    baclground-color: $primary-color
  }
  // ...

  // STATES
  &.#{$prefix}--btn--pressed, &.#{$prefix}--btn--hovered, &.#{$prefix}--btn--focused {
    cursor: pointer;
    @include darken-background();
  }

  &.#{$prefix}--btn--disabled {
    background-color: $disbaled-color;
    color: $secondary-color;
    outline: none;
    cursor: no-drop !important;
  }
}
```

**classnames** is a simple javaScript utility for conditionally joining classNames together.

I also use a utility function **composeEventHandlers** to give the possibility to consumers to supply their own event listeners on top of the default listeners defined in the component.

My questions are:

1. Is this way of handling component's style state efficient ? How does in compare to using css :hover or :pressed ?
   I have some doubt because there is a layer of JS that intervenes to update the style, which may be bad for performance.
2. Am i using any bad practises elsewhere in my implementation ? Is there a better way or something to improve ?

It's one of the first components in my design system, and i am commited to adopt good practises from the beginning. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Styled components to hadle style with your states
here is the suitable example

```
const Input = styled.input<{ $inputColor?: string; }>`
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  color: ${props => props.$inputColor || "#BF4F74"};
  background: papayawhip;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

// Render a styled text input with the standard input color, and one with a custom input color
render(
  <div>
    <Input defaultValue="@probablyup" type="text" />
    <Input defaultValue="@geelen" type="text" $inputColor="rebeccapurple" />
  </div>
);
```

you can install dependancy from [styled component official website](https://styled-components.com/)

Example : https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: I explored using CSS-in-JS libraries, and i found that for certain use cases, It can impact performance negatively. Besides, and this is subjective, i strongly dislike CSS-in-JS.

Comment: @AchrafElKhamsi if you don't want to use css in js then you can css vaiables and update it on state change in this way we can update css using state.

here is an example how to update css variable from js
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables_javascript.asp 

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_var_js